# Tensor Product Behaviour

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I was recently studying tensor product of modules and I wondered that if we change ring $R$ then what changes will occur in the Tensor Product of Modules M & N over $R$?

Comment: I think you mean over $R$, which is a generic ring and not the real numbers.

Comment: You probably have missunderstood something.

Comment: The bigger $R$ is, the smaller $M\otimes_R N$ will be.

Answer (score 0):

Take two objects $M,N$. Then you can define the tensor product $M \otimes_R N$ if you can endow $M$ with a right $R$-module structure and if we can endow $N$ with a left $R$-module structure. The resulting object is an abelian group. If $M$ and $N$ have additional properties, for example if $M$ can be endowed with a left $R$-module structure too, then the tensor product is a left $R$-module.

If $R$ is a commutative ring then every left $R$-module is also a right $R$-module and viceversa, so that the tensor product of $M$ and $N$ is itself a right and left $R$-module. The more structure you give to $M$, $N$ and $R$, the more properties the tensor product will have.